# WSO2-AS Error when passing date to create solr date format.java.text.ParseException

Tags: wso2, wso2-as

I just download the archive of wso2as 5.3.0 and start on windows 10:

```
[2016-02-10 11:11:20,789]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.internal.CarbonCoreActivator} -  Starting WSO2 Carbon...
[2016-02-10 11:11:20,791]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.internal.CarbonCoreActivator} -  Operating System : Windows 10 10.0, amd64
[2016-02-10 11:11:20,793]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.internal.CarbonCoreActivator} -  Java Home        : C:\Java\jdk1.8.0_66\jre
[2016-02-10 11:11:20,795]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.internal.CarbonCoreActivator} -  Java Version     : 1.8.0_66
[2016-02-10 11:11:20,797]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.internal.CarbonCoreActivator} -  Java VM          : Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 25.66-b18,Oracle Corporation
[2016-02-10 11:11:20,800]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.internal.CarbonCoreActivator} -  Carbon Home      : C:\wso2\WSO2AS_5.3.0\bin\..
[2016-02-10 11:11:20,802]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.internal.CarbonCoreActivator} -  Java Temp Dir    : C:\wso2\WSO2AS_5.3.0\bin\..\tmp
[2016-02-10 11:11:20,805]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.internal.CarbonCoreActivator} -  User             : Teste, pt-BR, America/Sao_Paulo
```

After some time, these exceptions occurs:

```
[2016-02-10 11:12:08,838] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.registry.indexing.solr.SolrClient} -  Error when passing date to create solr date format.java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "Wed Feb 10 11:11:41 BRST 2016"
[2016-02-10 11:12:08,939] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.registry.indexing.solr.SolrClient} -  Error when passing date to create solr date format.java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "Wed Feb 10 11:11:40 BRST 2016"
[2016-02-10 11:12:08,938] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.registry.indexing.solr.SolrClient} -  Error when passing date to create solr date format.java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "Wed Feb 10 11:11:41 BRST 2016"
[2016-02-10 11:12:08,938] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.registry.indexing.solr.SolrClient} -  Error when passing date to create solr date format.java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "Wed Feb 10 11:11:40 BRST 2016"
[2016-02-10 11:12:08,935] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.registry.indexing.solr.SolrClient} -  Error when passing date to create solr date format.java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "Wed Feb 10 11:11:41 BRST 2016"
[2016-02-10 11:12:08,934] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.registry.indexing.solr.SolrClient} -  Error when passing date to create solr date format.java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "Wed Feb 10 11:11:41 BRST 2016"
[2016-02-10 11:12:08,933] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.registry.indexing.solr.SolrClient} -  Error when passing date to create solr date format.java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "Wed Feb 10 11:11:41 BRST 2016"
[2016-02-10 11:12:08,931] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.registry.indexing.solr.SolrClient} -  Error when passing date to create solr date format.java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "Wed Feb 10 11:11:41 BRST 2016"
[2016-02-10 11:12:08,930] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.registry.indexing.solr.SolrClient} -  Error when passing date to create solr date format.java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "Wed Feb 10 11:11:41 BRST 2016"
[2016-02-10 11:12:08,928] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.registry.indexing.solr.SolrClient} -  Error when passing date to create solr date format.java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "Wed Feb 10 11:11:41 BRST 2016"
[2016-02-10 11:12:08,925] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.registry.indexing.solr.SolrClient} -  Error when passing date to create solr date format.java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "Wed Feb 10 11:11:41 BRST 2016"
[2016-02-10 11:12:08,924] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.registry.indexing.solr.SolrClient} -  Error when passing date to create solr date format.java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "Wed Feb 10 11:11:41 BRST 2016"
[2016-02-10 11:12:08,922] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.registry.indexing.solr.SolrClient} -  Error when passing date to create solr date format.java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "Wed Feb 10 11:11:41 BRST 2016"
[2016-02-10 11:12:08,920] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.registry.indexing.solr.SolrClient} -  Error when passing date to create solr date format.java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "Wed Feb 10 11:11:40 BRST 2016"
[2016-02-10 11:12:08,919] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.registry.indexing.solr.SolrClient} -  Error when passing date to create solr date format.java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "Wed Feb 10 11:11:41 BRST 2016"
[2016-02-10 11:12:08,919] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.registry.indexing.solr.SolrClient} -  Error when passing date to create solr date format.java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "Wed Feb 10 11:11:41 BRST 2016"
[2016-02-10 11:12:08,917] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.registry.indexing.solr.SolrClient} -  Error when passing date to create solr date format.java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "Wed Feb 10 11:11:41 BRST 2016"
[2016-02-10 11:12:08,915] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.registry.indexing.solr.SolrClient} -  Error when passing date to create solr date format.java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "Wed Feb 10 11:11:41 BRST 2016"
...
```

After some search, i found this issue https://wso2.org/jira/browse/REGISTRY-2977
But this is only solve for WSO2 Governance Registry.
Exists the solution for WSO2 Application Server?

Answer (score 2):

I added the following Java Options in my startscript of APIM1.10.:

```
-Duser.region=US -Duser.country=US -Duser.language=us
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, but is an workaround, its works.. I´m searching for the solution definitive. If I find out, I´ll post here.

Comment: Btw it should be: -Duser.language=en

Answer (score 1):

You can change your system locale to English. this is a workaround.

Comment: thanks for the answer, but is an workaround, I tested changing only the JVM and works.. I´m searching for the solution definitive. If I find out, I´ll post here.

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround, I have a system operative in spanish, I changed date format  in Control Panel to English (United States)